# App crash while getting data from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, crash

First of all I'm sorry I don't speak very good english. I'm currently developing an android app with eclipse and I have problem while fetching data from database. This is the method to read data from database. I put this method in a class named SQLiteAdapter:

```
 public Cursor getQuestionEachLevel(long levelId)
 {
     return sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_ANSWER,        
     KEY_QUESTION, KEY_HINT, KEY_FLAG, KEY_LEVEL}, KEY_LEVEL + "=" + levelId,
     null, null, null, null, null);
 }
```

And this is the code that going to call that method and fetch the data. I put this code in another class.

```
    int x=0;
    String getId[] = null;
    String getAnswer[] = null;
    String getQuestion[] = null;
    String getHint[] = null;
    String getFlag[]= null;
    String getLevel[]= null;

            mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
            Cursor c = mySQLiteAdapter.getQuestionEachLevel(getLevelKey);
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            getId[x] = c.getString(0);
            getAnswer[x] = c.getString(1);
            getQuestion[x] = c.getString(2);
            getHint[x] = c.getString(3);
            getFlag[x] = c.getString(4);
            getLevel[x] = c.getString(5);
            x++;
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```

I want to put each of the data from the database column into specific Variable because I'm going to use it later. Eclipse doesn't show any error but when I try to run this app on my phone, the app crash while fetching the data. Anyone know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Please post what error are you getting....

Comment: the logcat doesn't show anything wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your logcat, by all means. But in the meantime

```
int x=0;
String getId[] = null;
String getAnswer[] = null;
String getQuestion[] = null;
String getHint[] = null;
String getFlag[]= null;
String getLevel[]= null;
```

and afterwards

```
do{
        getId[x] = c.getString(0);
        getAnswer[x] = c.getString(1);
        getQuestion[x] = c.getString(2);
        getHint[x] = c.getString(3);
        getFlag[x] = c.getString(4);
        getLevel[x] = c.getString(5);
        x++;
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

is always pretty problematic... (your arrays aren't initialized and you're attempting to access them. I'd advise this change:

```
    int x=0;
List<String> getId = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> getAnswer = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String>getQuestion = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> getHint = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String>getFlag= new ArrayList<String>();
List<String>getLevel = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and afterwards

```
 do{
        getId.add( c.getString(0));
        getAnswer.add(  c.getString(1));
        getQuestion.add(c.getString(2));
        getHint.add(c.getString(3));
        getFlag.add(c.getString(4));
        getLevel.add(c.getString(5));
        x++;
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Look at my expanded answer. By using ArrayList you don't need to have the size beforehand but can add the items nonetheless...

Comment: You're welcome. A tip, though: learn to use the logcat! I'm pretty sure there was some information there.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize all the arrays before using it.

```
int x=0;
String getId[] = null;
String getAnswer[] = null;
String getQuestion[] = null;
String getHint[] = null;
String getFlag[]= null;
String getLevel[]= null;

       mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
       mySQLiteAdapter.openToRead();
       Cursor c = mySQLiteAdapter.getQuestionEachLevel(getLevelKey);
       if(c.moveToFirst()){
       int numOfRows = c.getCount();
       getId = new String[numOfRows];
       getAnswer = new String[numOfRows];
       getQuestion = new String[numOfRows];
       getHint = new String[numOfRows];
       getFlag = new String[numOfRows];
       getLevel = new String[numOfRows];
    do{
        getId[x] = c.getString(0);
        getAnswer[x] = c.getString(1);
        getQuestion[x] = c.getString(2);
        getHint[x] = c.getString(3);
        getFlag[x] = c.getString(4);
        getLevel[x] = c.getString(5);
        x++;
    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
mySQLiteAdapter.close();
```